# Direct URL to delete a SonicWALL adress object?

Tags: firewall

In the [SonicWALL Network Security Appliance](https://www.sonicwall.com/products/sonicwall-nsa/) web interface under Network > Address Objects one can check an address object box then Delete the item. Is there a way to specify a URL to directly delete an address object w/o having to navigate through to this point? Something like `https://sw.abc.org/address-object.html?delete=158`?

[image: SonicWALL Network Security Appliance > Network > Address Object > Delete]

Comment: Just because this uses a web interface doesn't mean that it automatically should be asked at Web Apps. I think you'll be much better off asking at [su] or [sf] (depending on whether this is a corporate network). Even [security.se] is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

SonicWALL address objects are pointed to unique id values which are generated by the system, hence this is not possible for a human to guess and there is no way to access its table.

The best way to delete if you are planning for a huge number is through the CLI, get the CLI guide and then create a template, copy + paste on the terminal session and you are good to go with the commit command.